# Possible to remove the time and just want the date from getTime() Date class?

Tags: java

Is it possible to remove the day (Fri), the time (22:34:21) and the time zone (GMT) by just having an output like "Jan 11 1980" instead of "Fri Jan 11 22:34:21 GMT 1980"??

Code below:

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1980);
date.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 11);

Date dob = date.getTime();

System.out.println(dob);//Fri Jan 11 22:34:21 GMT 1980
```

Many thanks!

Comment: use `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: ^^ What he said.  Here's [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  There are one trillion related questions on this site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Date date = new Date(); 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy"); 
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Output:

```
Feb 26 2013
```

If you want a specific date, do

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(1980, 0, 11);
Date date = c.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Prints

```
Jan 11 1980
```

Comment: And, if you get the formatter as: DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT); the output will be localised to the JVM language.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class DateFormat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        date.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1980);
        date.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
        date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 11);
        Date dob = date.getTime();
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy").format(dob));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Jan 11 1980
```

Answer (score 1):

`Date` is a representation of the number of milliseconds since the epoch (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT)

In order to "remove" the time portion of a `Date`, you will want to use a `DateFormat`

Something as simple as;

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(dob));
```

Should work.

For a more localised version, you should use [`DateFormat.getDateInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)

```
System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(dob));
System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(dob));
System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(dob));
System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG).format(dob));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat dateFormatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
System.out.println(dateFormatter.format(date);
```

This will print the only the date corresponding to your current system locale settings.

See also: [DateFormat in the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");

System.out.println(sdf.format(dob));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use:

```
stringToPrint = time.getMonth()+" "+time.getDate()+" "+time.getYear();
```

for more info:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: Seriously?  Every method you've listed is deprecated.  And you provided a link to Java 4 documentation??!?  This is **NOT** the correct appraoch.  You should use either the [Calendar API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) or [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  Java 4 is older than dirt and the methods were _already_ deprectated then!